# How to get array of double from audio file audio.row with Qt

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, audio

I captured sound (audio.raw ) from microphone  with  the function audioinput of Qt, 
now I want to get an array of double  from this audio file  and the I want make fft with fftw.

how cann I get this array from audiofile? and can can use it with fftw

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I assume you are using `QAudioInput` to get audio data. It provides a `QIODevice` that can be read to a `QByteArray`. Also you should provide `QAudioFormat` object when creating `QAudioInput`. Interpretation of `QByteArray` highly depends on properties of used format (at least `sampleType`, `sampleSize` and `byteOrder`).

Comment: please can you show an example of c++ code ?